# How to produce non-standard plot type with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot with ggplot that looks very close to this ([found here](http://learnr.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/chapter04-04_05_r.png)):

[image]

However, instead of frequency I would like to plot ranges for conditions. Here is a sketch of the plot I want to produce with 5 conditions:

[image]

My data is arranged as a start and end coordinate for the range. For example, for condition 5 the start of the range is 30 and the end of the range is 40 (I've labeled this about the graph for clarity). My data is from a file in the form:

```
id      start   end
1       20      35
2       60      75    
3       10      30
4       80      90
5       30      40
```

I have about 100 start and end values that I would like to plot in this manner on one graph. The final plot should be only two colors.

UPDATE:

For future reference, Justin's solution produces this:

[image]

Comment: very nicely specified question!

Comment: Thanks for your update to show to solution's plot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
dat <- data.frame(lets=letters[1:5], low=1:5, mid=3:7, high=10:14)
dat.melt <- melt(dat, id.vars='lets')


ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x=lets, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c('low','mid','high'), values=c('blue','red','blue')) +
  coord_flip()
```

But fairly dependent on your data...

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I am looking for. I'm still having trouble melting my data into the correct data structure for your example. How can I melt my data like `dat.melt`? I tried `melt(id, start, end)`, but that didn't work. I've edited my question to show the structure of my data. Thanks.

Comment: `melt(yourdata, id.vars='id')` will give you a structure like what I have.  You can also replace the first color with `NA` so that only the shaded section in your picture is colored.

Comment: to reproduce the figure in the original post, use: `dat <- data.frame(lets=1:5, low=c(20,60,10,80,30), mid=c(15,15,20,10,10), high=c(65,25,70,10,60))`